# is it possible to get default created or updated time for attributes from neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j

I have created Nodelabel with properties in neo4j. i was trying to get default created time for nodelabel or properties and relationships.

Comment: Could you add the code you tried?

Comment: i tried this query which returns current time stamp-->"MATCH (a:YES) RETURN timestamp()"

Comment: Directly in the question, and add all the relevant code to let the others help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

neo4j does not automatically store the times at which a property was created or updated.

If you want those times, you will have to write the code to store extra creation-time and update-time properties yourself.

For example, during creation:

```
CREATE (f:Foo {name: 'Fred', nameCreated: timestamp()})
```

and during update:

```
MATCH (f:Foo {name: 'Fred'})
SET f.name = 'Freddy', f.nameUpdated = timestamp();
```